# Terraform Enterprise module file location error

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

Need some assistance regarding using files with in modules from terraform enterprise.  Git top folder structure is like this:

- modules
- README.md
- main.tf

With in the modules the folder structure is like this:

- modules

  - main.tf
  - file1.json

the main.tf within modules referring these file1.json through
like below

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "deny_bill_policy" {
  name = "OpsPolicy"
  path = "/"
  policy = "${file("${path.module}/file1.json")}"
}
```

The same program runs without any issues from my localpc to deploy on aws but when i run the same through terraform enterprise which pulls repo from git throwing the following error.

- module.policy_roles.aws_iam_policy.deny_bill_policy: file: open file1.json: no such file or directory in: ${file("${path.module}/file1.json")}

fyi - there is no previous/old .terraform dir existed. Seems TFE handling module/paths is different. some one please assist me here.